# Wordpress - Is there a way to see exactly in which file I can find an element's code

Tags: php, file, element, inspect

Is there a way for me, similar to inspect element, to choose an element and see exactly where the code for the element is written?

It can be a plugin, extension - basically anything. I just need to find the code for an element that's causing me some trouble.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

I found this amazing plugin called [String Locator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/string-locator/). It does exactly what I needed.

Kind regards